# Show function to super admin

Tags: plugins, functions, multisite, network-admin

How do I limit information being applied only to Network Administrators?

TL;DR;
I am building a multisite for a City Council where every member will have its own subdomain.
In one of the plugins, I want to limit some menu options to be shown only to the users with the network admin role.

I found this from almost 5 years ago but it doesn't work:

```
 <?php

function check_for_superAdmin($user_login, $user) {
    $current_user = get_userdatabylogin($user_login);
    if ( is_super_admin( $current_user->ID ) ) {
        // do these things 
    <?php if ( $purchase_code != '' ): ?>
        <small class="text-muted form-text">
           <?php printf(
                __( '<a class="%s" href="#">Click here</a> to dissociate this purchase code from the current domain (use to move the plugin to another site).', 'bookly' ), 'bookly-js-detach-pc'
            ) ?>
        </small>
    <?php endif ?>

        }
    else { // do other things 

    }
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'check_for_superAdmin', 10, 2 );

?>
```

The idea is that only SuperAdmin can mess with the purchase code from Bookly (a non-GPL plugin) but I may reuse the code for other functions.

What do I need to change? What would be the best way to first check that the user has the network admin role?

Thanks,

AG

Comment: It would be helpful if you could [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/366842/edit) to include the code that you've tried. Also, look into [`is_super_admin()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_super_admin/) or use a [capability](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#super-admin) that Super Admins have in a Multisite installation (such as `manage_network`).